# C# create DLL Plugin that implements interface

Tags: c#, dll, load

I'm writing a simple plugin based program. I have an interface `IPlugin` which has some methods and functions, and a `List<Plugin>` in my main program. For the sake of simplicity, lets say its defined like this:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    public void OnKeyPressed(char key);
}
```

Everytime a key is pressed, I loop through the Plugin list, and call `OnKeyPressed(c)` on each of them.

I can create a class like so, and add it to the list...

```
public class PrintPlugin
{
    public void OnKeyPressed(char key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

And then whenever you press a key, its printed out. But I want to be able to load plugins from DLL files. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087794/c-load-a-dll-file-and-access-methods-from-class-within) was helpful, but it doesn't explain how to have the classes in the DLL implement my `IPlugin` interface... How can I do that? I really don't want to have to copy the `IPlugin.cs` file every time I want to make a plugin...

Comment: You can add reference to your library, and since that you can use your plugin interface.

Comment: I want to be able to load them at runtime, so that the users can create their own plugins.

Comment: Then you should create a property like `List<Plugin>`, so users can add their plugins to your list.

Comment: I already have one of those, if you read the original post. My problem is, I want the plugin writers to be able to implement my `IPlugin` interface in their plugins.

Comment: You should share your IPlugin assembly to the `plugin writers`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly...

Create 3 Projects:

Project 1: Your main program (the one with List in it)

Project 2: the project with your interface

```
public interface IPlugin
{
public void OnKeyPressed(char key);
}
```

Project 3: A sample Plugin

```
public class PrintPlugin : IPlugin
{
public void OnKeyPressed(char key)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
}
```

Then Add project 2 as a reference to both project 1 and 3.

This way you share the interface with both your main project and any of your plugins.

I have used this on a couple of projects and it has served me well.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/) as well.  It provide a complete API for writing plugin based programs and covers a lot of concerns such as security if you're ever going to plan to make the plugin API available to third parties.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load user defined plugins, you should search for new DLLs when the application starts (or any other action).  This can be done by using:

1)  [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) method returns the list of loaded assemblies in the current AppDomain

2)  Search all DLLs in a folder where plugins should be positioned and check if a certain assembly is in the list.  If not, use the [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) method to load this assembly, find the IPlugin class in it and finally add it to the List object.