# Loading dll from other folder

Tags: c#, c

My c# application is loading a C# dll. This c# dll loads a c dll through DllImport. I want that both of these dlls are present in other folder then that of the current working directory. But I dont want to modify it environment variable. I tried SetDllDirectory but unable to load these dlls. 
Do you have any idea how i can do it.

Comment: are you loading it through reflection?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087794/c-sharp-load-a-dll-file-and-access-methods-from-class-within

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you sure it's because of the folders?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to Your config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <probing privatePath="FolderName;OtherFolderName"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Those folders need to be subdirectories of your app directory.

Comment: I am able to load c# dll by specifying path in LoadFrom but not able to load C dll(Loaded by C# Dll). If i try LoadLibrary in the application i am able to load C# and C dll both so SetDll directory is working fine. If i place all the dlls in current folder then application runs fine.
the probing tag only loads the C# dll but unable to load its dependencies from other folder. In this case it is C dll.