# C# load DLL at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, import

I made a C# library somewhat like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void WriteHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }
}
```

I compiled it into a DLL file.

Now I want to import this DLL file. Every page or site that says how to import a DLL does it from *outside* the code, such as adding a reference in visual studio. I couldn't find any way to import my DLL using just code. I tried `DllImport`, read the documentation, and `DllImport` threw a ton of errors.

Is there another way to import a DLL into my C# application?

Comment: You can load an Assembly via Assembly.Load. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=net-6.0

Comment: Use reflection to call the assembly

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? You *can* load an assembly via Assembly.Load, but unless you are trying to do something like a plugin system you should probably just add it as a regular reference. DllImport is for calling native functions, and is probably not what you want.

Comment: What do I do after Assembly.load?

Comment: Search for your type in that assembly and search for the method you want to call. That is normally called "reflection". You can't simply call `MyClass.WriteHello()` because you only know that stuff now at runtime. When you want to simply call stuff in code you need to know that at compile time before the code runs. Aka referencing it (what you don't want to do) so you can use it while programming and not only when the code runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Do you *really* need to import it at runtime?

Chances are, you probably don't. It is a real pain to import it at runtime, and you probably don't really need to do it. It's a lot easier to just import it from outside the code, using a reference.

#### If you are using Visual Studio

On the top of the window, click on "Project", then click on "Add Project Reference". A dialog will appear. From there, click "Browse" (on the bottom right corner), and select the DLL file, then click "OK". Then, you can call `WriteHello` using the code `MyClass.WriteHello()`. No need to import it.

#### If you are using the .NET cli add this to your `.csproj` file.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
    <HintPath>path\to\lib.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

#### If you are using csc to compile your application, use this.

```
csc.exe /path/to/application.cs /t:exe /out:/path/to/application.exe /r:/path/to/library.dll
```

The most important part of that command is the `/r:` which adds the reference.

### I'm not convinced to use a reference, I still want to load it at runtime!

In this case, use `System.Reflection.Assembly`. Use `Assembly.LoadFrom`, to load the DLL file, like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("/path/to/lib.dll")
```

Next, get the `WriteHello` object from your dll.

```
Type MyClass = assembly.GetType("lib.MyClass")
```

Next, invoke `WriteHello`.

```
MyClass.Methods[0].Invoke(); // MyClass.Methods[0] is your WriteHello function and .Invoke invokes WriteHello.
```

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
class Program
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("/path/to/lib.dll");
        Type MyClass = example.GetType("lib.MyClass");

        MyClass.GetMethods[0].Invoke();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I really should just add a reference....... :(