# What is the implementation of System.load(dll) in C#?

Tags: c#, java

I am on the way of learning java and I wanted to know what is the  System.load(dll) parallel/ implementation of this in C#..is it like the "using" statement? I am a c# developer so maybe by having an example it will be better for me to understand it

Comment: So you want this in C# or Java??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can use Reflection to load library dynamically in runtime:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly myDllAssembly = 
   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("%MyDLLPath%\\MyDLL.dll");
```

After that you'll be able to search for types from that assemble:

```
System.Type MyDLLFormType = myDllAssembly.GetType("MyDLLNamespace.MyDLLForm");
```

And create object of that type:

```
Form MyDLLFormInstance = (Form)myDllAssembly.CreateInstance("MyDLLNamespace.MyDLLForm");
```

Answer (score 1):

**In java** :to Load a Java Native/Dynamic Library (DLL) , [see this example :](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Windows.asp)

```
import com.chilkatsoft.CkZip;

public class Test {

  static {
    try {
        System.load("C:/chilkatJava/chilkat.dll");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) 
  {
    CkZip zip = new CkZip();
    System.out.println(zip.version());    
  }
}
```

**In C#**: try this link Answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087851/1743852

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you cannot load a native dll, instead you P/Invoke them!

> P/Invoke, or Pinvoke stands for Platform Invocation Services.  PInvoke
>   is a feature of the Microsoft .NET Frameowrk that allows a developer
>   to make calls to native code inside Dynamic Link Libraries (DLL’s). 
>   When Pinvoking, the .NET framework (or Common Language Routine) will
>   load the DLL and handle the type conversions automatically.  The most
>   common use of P/Invoke is to use a feature of Windows that is only
>   contained in the Win32 API.  The API in Windows is extremely extensive
>   and only some of the features are encapsulated in .NET libraries.